# How to filter by Time from DateTime values in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My `df` dataset looks likes this:

```
time                    Open
2017-01-03 06:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 07:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 08:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-03 09:00:00     5.2128
2017-01-03 10:00:00     5.2128
2017-01-04 06:00:00     5.4122
2017-01-04 07:00:00     5.4122
2017-01-04 08:00:00     5.2123
2017-01-04 09:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-04 10:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-05 07:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-05 08:00:00     5.2128
2017-01-05 09:00:00     5.4122
2017-01-05 10:00:00     5.4122
....
```

I want to filter `time` values starting from `'07:00:00'` and include next `3` values

My new `df` should look like this:

```
time                    Open
2017-01-03 07:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 08:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-03 09:00:00     5.2128
2017-01-04 07:00:00     5.4122
2017-01-04 08:00:00     5.2123
2017-01-04 09:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-05 07:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-05 08:00:00     5.2128
2017-01-05 09:00:00     5.4122
....
```

Here, we are not including the `'06:00:00'` or `'10:00:00'` since we are only getting the data starting from `'07:00:00'` and the next `3` values

We need to preserve the order of the original `df` and just remove unwanted data in between that does not match the criteria of starting from `'07:00:00'` and `3` values after `'07:00:00'`

**What did I do?**

I tried to filter by selecting the `time` part but it only gives me one value when I do this:

```
df[(df.index.time == datetime.time(07, 0))
```

but I want the next `3` values. Doing `head(3)` does not work:

```
df[(df.index.time == datetime.time(07, 0))].head(3)
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

use [`between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) to fetch data on the basis of time

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"time":["2017-01-03 07:00:00","2017-01-03 06:00:00","2017-01-03 08:00:00","2017-01-03 10:00:00"],
                   "open":[5,5,5,4]})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.set_index("time",inplace=True)

res = df.between_time('07:00:00','09:00:00')
print(res)
```

```
time                     
2017-01-03 07:00:00     5
2017-01-03 08:00:00     5
2017-01-03 09:00:00     4
```

## addition to your question

```
date_list = ['2017-01-03', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-07']
res =res[res.index.normalize().isin(date_list)]
```

## in order to ignore last_date you can do

```
res=res[(res.index >='2017-01-02') &(res.index < '2017-01-07')]
```

Comment: Thanks for composing the answer. After the `time` filter is done, how can I filter by `Date`? Let us say I want to load the `Date` data form the `date_list = ['2017-01-03', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-07']`

Comment: I am not sure why, but, it seems like it is `sorting` the `date_list` and also not including the last `date` `'2017-01-07'`

Comment: it will include last date,isin function will include all dates including in a list

Comment: try to do another question if your initial question is answered ,in this way more people can answer it

Comment: if you find my answer helpful kindly upvote or accept

Answer (score 0):

Compare values by time and create helper `Series` by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then remove values with `0`, because it is first values non matched first time from condition and use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
s = pd.Series(df.index.time == datetime.time(7, 0), index=df.index).cumsum()
df = df[s != 0].groupby(s).head(3)
print (df)
                       Open
time                       
2017-01-03 07:00:00  5.2475
2017-01-03 08:00:00  5.2180
2017-01-03 09:00:00  5.2128
2017-01-04 07:00:00  5.4122
2017-01-04 08:00:00  5.2123
2017-01-04 09:00:00  5.2475
2017-01-05 07:00:00  5.2180
2017-01-05 08:00:00  5.2128
2017-01-05 09:00:00  5.4122
```

If need filter by hours and by dates with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
date_list = ['2017-01-03', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-07']
df = df[df.index.hour.isin([7,8,9]) & df.index.floor('d').isin(date_list)]
print (df)
                       Open
time                       
2017-01-03 07:00:00  5.2475
2017-01-03 08:00:00  5.2180
2017-01-03 09:00:00  5.2128
```

Or by times and dates:

```
date_list = ['2017-01-03', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-07']
times = [datetime.time(7, 0), datetime.time(8, 0), datetime.time(9, 0)]
df = df[np.in1d(df.index.time, times) & df.index.floor('d').isin(date_list)]
print (df)
                       Open
time                       
2017-01-03 07:00:00  5.2475
2017-01-03 08:00:00  5.2180
2017-01-03 09:00:00  5.2128
```

Comment: Thank you for composing the answer. It looks like it works but the final `df` is sorted. We are supposed to preserve the order of `date_list` and the `time`. It should not be sorted in any way.

Comment: @floss it depends what need, but timeseries best working with sirting datetimeindex. Order of values in list does not matters

Comment: For the calculation I am working on, I need the order of `date` and `time` preserved. The `date_list = ['2017-01-07', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-03']` here is in random order and it should maintain the order, including the corresponding `time`